# Why is multithreading a member function in tkinter not thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am trying to understand why multithreading member functions is not safe in most GUI toolkits.

For example, when using tkinter in Python:

```
from tkinter import Tk
from threading import Thread


class Form (Tk):

    def __init__(self):

        Tk.__init__(self)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_close)

        self.stop_thread = False
        self.print_thread = None


    def start_thread(self):

        self.print_thread = Thread(target = self.print)
        self.print_thread.start()


    def print(self):

        i = 0
        while self.stop_thread != True:
            print(i)
            i += 1



     def on_close(self):
         self.stop_thread = True
         if self.print_thread != None:
             self.print_thread.join()

 form = Form()
 form.start_thread()
 form.mainloop()
```

I have implemented this same concept without using a gui toolkit in python and it works as expected. However, when using tkinter, it freezes the program when closing the window. Can someone explain to me in detail what is going on behind the scenes and why the program hangs?

Comment: Asking about "most toolkits" is far too broad for StackOverflow. Nobody can give a proper answer that addresses most toolkits.

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with the thread. Comment out the `form.start_thread()` line and you'll get the same result.

The problem is that you took over the built-in close command, so now it's up to you to destroy the window.

```
def on_close(self):
    self.stop_thread = True
    if self.print_thread != None:
         self.print_thread.join()
    self.destroy() # <== call the function that's normally bound to the close event
```

That said, for applications where you don't mind the thread abruptly closing, there's a much easier way to ensure a thread closes when the main thread closes: make it a daemon thread.

```
from tkinter import Tk
from threading import Thread
import time

def print_loop():
    i = 0
    while True:
        print(i)
        time.sleep(0.001) # < == critical
        i += 1

class Form (Tk):
    def start_thread(self):
        my_thread = Thread(target = print_loop, daemon=True)
        my_thread.start()

form = Form()
form.start_thread()
form.mainloop()
```

Comment: Daemon threads don't have safe shutdown, though. They're abruptly terminated when all non-daemon threads finish, **bypassing `finally` blocks, `__exit__` methods, and any other cleanup**.

Comment: Yes, true, they are certainly not to be used for all cases. Depends on what OP's actual use case is.